# transliteration in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to transliterate DNA strings to generate reverse complement in the following way... And then look for matches in a large DNA string using the generated output as pattern

`$revcomp = reverse($dna);`

`$revcomp =~ tr/ACGTacgt[]{}N/TGCAtgca][}{./;`

For example:
If this is my input string,

`C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC`

I would like my output to be

`GCAT[ACGT]{5,8}[CT]{7,10}G`

But, what I end up getting is : `GCAT{8,5}[ACGT]{01,7}[CT]G`

Any help??

Comment: so you are really trying to reverse a regular expression

Comment: Your problem is that you try to reverse a "modular" expression by reversing the atoms, which does not work. You need to identify each literal part of the expression, e.g. `C`, `[AG]{7,10}`, `[ACGT]{5,8}` and `ATGC` separately and then reverse and transliterate. Might be rather tricky to identify all possible regex meta-characters.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the DNA string representation you are using, but this code works with your data.

It looks for individual items in the DNA string, where an item can a sequence of one or more `ACGT` bases, or a sequence in square brackets followed by a pair of repeat counts in braces. I have assumed there will never be just a single repeat count, but this code is easy to modify if that is a possibility.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq = 'C[AG]{7,10}[ACGT]{5,8}ATGC';
my $rev = '';

while (1) {
  if ($seq =~ /\G([ATGC]+)/igc) {
    (my $new = reverse $1) =~ tr/ACGTacgt/TGCAtgca/;
    $rev = $new.$rev;
  }
  elsif ($seq =~ /\G\[([ATGC]+)\]\{(\d+),(\d+)\}/igc) {
    (my $new = reverse $1) =~ tr/ACGTacgt/TGCAtgca/;
    $rev = "[$new]{$2,$3}".$rev;
  }
  else {
    last;
  }
}

print $rev;
```

**output**

```
GCAT[ACGT]{5,8}[CT]{7,10}G
```